# MEAN CRUD error crash cant set headers

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, crud

So my CRUD app at this time, does two things, keeps sending an infinite empty list. But not just that, when I try to delete something I get this error... Jump below for the api code. Also if you see anything that might contribute to an infinite list lemme know.

```
C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:419
        throw err;
              ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_modul
es\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:63:22)
    at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_
modules\express\lib\response.js:526:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_modules\ex
press\lib\response.js:193:36)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\routes\api.js:45:21
)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_modules\mongoo
se\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:162:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_modules\mongoose\node
_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:79:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_modules\mongoose\n
ode_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:92:20)
    at C:\Users\\Desktop\Todo List\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1736:
26
```

routes api code

```
var Todo = require('../app/models/todos').Todo;

   exports.read = function(req, res) {

        // use mongoose to get all todos in the database
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {

            // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
            if (!err)
                res.send(err)

            res.json(todos); // return all todos in JSON format
        });
    };

    // create todo and send back all todos after creation
   exports.create = function(req, res) {

        // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
        Todo.create({text : req.body.text}, function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(todos);

            // get and return all the todos after you create another
            Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(todos);
            });
        });

    };

    // delete a todo
   exports.delete = function(req, res) {
        Todo.remove({_id : req.params._id
        }, function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(todos);

            // get and return all the todos after you create another
            Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(todos);
            });
        });
    };

    //Update a todo
    exports.update = function(req, res) {
        Todo.findById(req.params._id, function(err, todos){
            todos.text = req.body.text;
            console.log(todos);
            todos.save(function() {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send(todos);
                } else if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }

                Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err)
                    res.json(todos);
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually see this error when I'm using `res` multiple times in my Express route by mistake. Be sure that in route handler (function) you are only using `res` once.

For example

```
app.get('/foo', doFoo);

function doFoo(req, res) {
  res.send('foo');
  res.send('bar');
}
```

won't work since you're trying to use res twice which internally calls `res.end()` if I'm not mistaken.

Edit: As it turns out, I think I see the problem in your code.

```
// create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
Todo.create({text : req.body.text}, function(err, todos) {
    if (err)
        res.send(todos);

    // get and return all the todos after you create another
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(todos);
    });
});
```

Here, you're using `res.send(todos)` in the event that you receive an error from your first call to `Todo.create`. Assuming you do receive an error here, your code will still attempt `Todo.find`. Once that happens, it will then try `res.json(todos)` thereby firing two responses and resulting in the error that you see about not being able to set response headers after they're already sent. I think you can fix your code by using actual `else` statements to ensure you don't send two responses.

```
    Todo.create({text:req.body.text}, function(err, todos){
      if (err) {...}
      else {
        .. your else code here
      }

});
```

Comment: I tried removing the res.send but that didn't solve it either. Updated with code above.